# Get UItextField from inputView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have `UITextField`. I set `UIDatePicker` as inputView for this `UITextField`

```
UITextField *dateField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        dateField.frame = CGRectMake(30, 180, 260, 30);
        dateField.delegate = self;
        [self addSubview:dateField];

        UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
        [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
        datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 568 - 100, 320, 100);
        [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [dateField setInputView:datePicker];

-(void)updateTextField:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"SENDER = %@", sender);
}
```

Is there any way to get `UITextField` inside `updateTextField` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this and create ivar currentTextField

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {


     currentTextField = textField;


}
```

currentTextField  in updateTextField will be your text filed

Comment: Is there any way without using global variables?

Comment: Use the answer from Greg

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can get reference to the textView like that:

```
-(void)updateTextField:(id)sender
{
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = (UIDatePicker*) sender;
    UITextField *dateField = (UITextField*)datePicker.inputView;
}
```

//Extended

Sorry my mistake I thought that you add text field as a input view to data picker.
The other way you can do what you want is assign tag to your text view where you set up it:

```
UITextField *dateField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
dateField.frame = CGRectMake(30, 180, 260, 30);
dateField.tag = 10;
dateField.delegate = self;
[self addSubview:dateField];
```

And in your method updateTextField: you can access it like:

```
UITextField *dateField = (UITextField*)[self viewWithTag:10];
```

Comment: I get UIDatePicker object instead UITextField object using your example

Comment: @KiselAlexander sorry it was my mistake, please see extended answer.

Comment: Greg, This example is not good for me, because I have several UITextFields.